# Langchain TextLoader not functioning properly

Tags: python, langchain, py-langchain, chromadb

ChromaDB and the Langchain text splitter are only processing and storing the first txt document that runs this code. Whenever I try to reference any documents added after the first, the LLM just says it does not have the information I just gave it but works perfectly on the first document. In addition, the first chunk size is massive, way over the specified 300. The second run does not even attempt to split the characters, not outputting anything about it being over the chunk size limit or anything. Any help would be appreciated!

Output:
Created a chunk of size 35393, which is longer than the specified 300

```
        loader = TextLoader("./folder/file.txt")
        documents = loader.load()
        text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=300, chunk_overlap=0)
        chromaDirectory = "./folder/chroma_db"
        Chroma.from_documents(texts, embeddings, persist_directory=chromaDirectory)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit sparse on the whole process you're talking about. It seems like you're only dealing with one document in the code. Try loading all the documents separately using Langchain's RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter. It can handle big chunks of text and split them up based on a chunk size you set. See an example below and adjust the code based on your needs:

```
from langchain.docstore.document import Document
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.document_loaders import TextLoader
from chromadb.config import Settings

DOC_LOADERS_MAPPING = {
    ".txt": (TextLoader, {"encoding": "utf8"}),
    # Include more document loaders if needed
}

def load_document(path: str) -> Document:
    try:
        ext = "." + path.rsplit(".", 1)[-1]
        if ext in DOC_LOADERS_MAPPING:
            loader_class, loader_args = DOC_LOADERS_MAPPING[ext]
            loader = loader_class(path, **loader_args)

            return loader.load()[0]
        
        raise ValueError(f"Unsupported file extension: {ext}")
    except Exception as exception:
        raise ValueError(f"Error loading document: {exception}")

def load_documents_from_dir(path: str) -> List[Document]:
    try:
        all_files = []
        for ext in DOC_LOADERS_MAPPING:
            all_files.extend(
                glob.glob(os.path.join(path, f"**/*{ext}"), recursive=True)
                )
        
        return [load_document(path) for path in all_files]
    except Exception as exception:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Error loading files: {exception}")

    
documents = load_documents_from_dir("./folder/")
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
    chunk_size=300,
    chunk_overlap=50
)
texts = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

chroma_db = Chroma.from_documents(
    texts,
    embeddings,
    persist_directory="./folder/chroma_db",
    client_settings= Settings(
            persist_directory="./folder/chroma_db",
            chroma_db_impl="duckdb+parquet",
            anonymized_telemetry=False,
        ),    
)
chroma_db.persist()
chroma_db = None
```

Comment: I looked at the code a little more and I think chromadb is the issue. Whenever I try to save a database from documents, I get a SIGTERM. I have no idea what could be causing this. Maybe the huggingface embeddings and the text? It dosen't happen on my mac but does on server.